# Polymer: import and bind templates from another file

Tags: polymer

Would it be possible to import templates from another file? I'm able to import javascript and stylesheet, but cannot figure out how to import html templates.

For example:

I defined various content-item templates in **templates.html**

```
<template id="hello>Hello {{ li.name }}</template>
<template id="hey">Hey!</template>
```

And then, I would like to re-use the templates in **list.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="templates.html">

<polymer-element name="list" attributes="type,data">

<template>

  <template repeat="{{ li in items_in_data }}">
     <template bind ref="hey"></template>
     <template bind ref="{{ type }}"></template>
  </template>

</template>


</polymer-element>
```

Finally, in **app.html**

```
<list data="items.json" type="hello"></list>
```

If I put the contents inside templates.html into list.html, it works fine. However, it does not seem to load or reference when using `<link rel="import">`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution: The below works in chrome but not polyfill browsers (e.g. firefox).  Need to look through polyfill code to figure out how to handle links in a file already linked.

The issue is that the content of the import is not inserted into the document but is just made available for use.  See [HTML5 Rocks imports - using content](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#usingcontent) for more details.  You can find all of the templates in the linked file and insert them into your polymer element's document fragment:

```
var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
var link = importDoc.querySelector('.myimports');
var templates = link.import.querySelectorAll('template'); 
for (var i=0;i<templates.length;i++) {
  importDoc.head.appendChild(templates[i]);
}
```

## Example

### demo-templates.html

```
<template id="hello">Hello World!</template>
<template id="goodbye">See you tomorrow</template>
```

### demo-importTemplates-list.html

```
<link class="myimports" rel="import" href="demo-templates.html">

<polymer-element name="demo-importTemplates-list">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{ li in data }}">
      <h1>{{li}}</h1>
      <template bind ref="hello"></template> -- <template bind ref="goodbye"></template>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      data: ['first','second','third']
    });

    // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#usingcontent
    // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#include-templates
    var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    var link = importDoc.querySelector('.myimports');
    var templates = link.import.querySelectorAll('template');
    for (var i=0;i<templates.length;i++) {
      importDoc.head.appendChild(templates[i]);
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

### index.html

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="../../webcomponents/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="demo-importTemplates-list.html">
  <title>demo-importTemplates</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <demo-importTemplates-list  type="hello"></demo-importTemplates-list>
 </body>
</html>
```